# XmlHttpRequest POST method fails with status code 400 in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11, http-status-code-400

I have a React app containing a JavaScript method which posts data to a server method. This method works fine in every browser under the sun...except IE11 (shocking I know). Unfortunately IE11 support is a requirement for this project.

IIS logs reveal 400 (bad request) HTTP status codes.

I chose not to use fetch() due to its incompatibility with IE11, and I'd rather avoid resorting to external libraries like axios or jQuery for a single method for a single browser.

I attempted a few `Content-Type` header values (application/json and x-url-form-encoded), and also tried various other headers which may or may not be related (Pragma, CORS - even though it's not cross-origin, Cache-Control et al.).

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
    const booking = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value3',
    };

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "api/Booking/AddBooking";

    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(booking));

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            this.setState({
                bookingResponse: response,
                showModal: true
            });
        }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I know the external libraries work with IE11 so there must be a way around this with vanilla JavaScript, I just can't find what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: SO in the network tab is there any other information provided?

Comment: Are you on an Active Directory (Domain controller) enterprise? If so, there may bea group policy in place that is forcing IE11 into Compatibility View.

Comment: @epascarello just:
`/api/Booking/AddBooking HTTPS POST 400  224 B 31 ms XMLHttpRequest 0 0 0 31 0 0`

@RandyCasburn The network uses AD but there are no compatibility settings for this URL.

Comment: I've checked the server method in debugging and it doesn't receive/accept the request's body when using IE11, so it appears to be related to the format the data is being sent. I've tried further variations to the data itself (e.g. arrays rather than objects), and the Content-Type header but to no avail. At the moment I'm looking to see if there are any differences in the request body between Chrome and IE using Fidldler but not having any luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to some of the variable values. I was using ES6 string interpolation (i.e. back ticks), which is unsupported in IE.